# Meteor.call from a Handlebars block helper

Tags: meteor

I am trying to use a `Meteor.call` function within a Handlebars block helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('get_handle', function(profileId, name) {
  Meteor.call("getProfileLink", profileId, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
      return new Handlebars.SafeString('<a href="#">' + name + '</a>');
    } else {
      return new Handlebars.SafeString('<a href="http://twitter.com/' + result + '">' + name + '</a>');
    }
  });
});
```

I see in `console.log(result)` that the result is being returned, but the HTML from this helper is not being rendered. However, when I put the same `Handlebars.SafeString` return value out of the `Meteor.call`, it works fine. What am I doing wrong here? Or is it not correct to use a `Meteor.call` in the Handlebars block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use Meteor.call in a handlebars block with the paradigm above, primarily because of javascript's asynchronous design, by the time a value is received from the server, the return value has already been returned.

You can however pass it through using a `Session` variable:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('get_handle', profileId, name,  function() {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(Session.get("get_handle" + profileId + "_" + name));

});


//In a meteor.startup or a template.render
Meteor.call("getProfileLink", profileId, name, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
       Session.set("get_handle" + profileId + "_" + name, '<a href="#">' + name + '</a>');
    } else {
       Session.set("get_handle" + profileId + "_" + name, '<a href="http://twitter.com/' + result + '">' + name + '</a>');
    }
});
```

Also be careful with trying to use have so many `Meteor.call` for each profileId and name (if you're using this in some sort of list or something) when you could request the data in one bulk request.

**Hacky way**

You can still do it the way you intend, but I would advise against it. I think its a bit inefficient.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('get_handle', profileId, name,  function() {
    if(Session.get("get_handle" + profileId + "_" + name)) {
        return new Handlebars.SafeString(Session.get("get_handle" + profileId + "_" + name));
    }
    else
    {
        Meteor.call("getProfileLink", profileId, name, function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                Session.set("get_handle" + profileId + "_" + name, '<a href="#">' + name + '</a>');
            } else {
                Session.set("get_handle" + profileId + "_" + name, '<a href="http://twitter.com/' + result + '">' + name + '</a>');
            }
        });
        return "Loading..."
     }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Akshat. I thought I'd rather add this as a field to the document and retrieve, instead of rendering later.

Comment: I've modified it and added a way for you to do that too

Comment: I think the simplest way is to store the handle while creating a document and render it while retrieving the list. I didn't store the handle field before. But thanks anyway. I love hacks :)