# Why does nothing display in my Meteor application?

Tags: javascript, json, meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

I've got this in my client.js file

```
Template.data.champ = Meteor.call("checkLeague", function(error, results) {
        console.log(results.data.data);
        return results.data.data;
});
```

So it shows fine in the console.log but it doesn't actually show on the webpage.

This is my html file with handlebars template

```
<body>
  {{> hello}}
  {{> data}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  {{greeting}}
  <input type="button" value="Click" />
</template>

<template name="data">
    {{#each champ}}
        {{name}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

From my understanding (which is very limited in terms of Handlebars) but the {{#each champ}} iterates over objects? But for some reason, nothing is being displayed on the page.

This is the object structure (displayed in the console).

```
Object {Aatrox: Object, Ahri: Object, Akali: Object, Alistar: Object, Amumu: Object…}
Aatrox: Object
   id: "Aatrox"
   image: Object
   key: "266"
   name: "Aatrox"
   title: "the Darkin Blade"
   __proto__: Object
Ahri: Object
Akali: Object
Alistar: Object
Amumu: Object
Anivia: Object
Annie: Object
Ashe: Object
```

So basically I am passing an object that has properties which have values of objects. I assume the {{#each} iterates over the properties and gives access to the values (which is an object) and then I try to access the `name` property of that variable in the `handlebars` template but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peppe's answer is correct - here is an option for how to deal with this situation:

```
Template.data.created = function() {
  Meteor.call('checkLeague', function(error, results) {
    Session.set('champ', results.data.data);
  });
};

Template.data.champ = function() {
  return Session.get('champ');
};
```

The data is loaded when the template is created, and asynchronously stored into a session variable. Keep in mind that this isn't reactive, but that's hard to overcome since your data is coming from a method call.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs regarding `Meteor.call`:

> If you include a callback function as the last argument (which can't
>   be an argument to the method, since functions aren't serializable),
>   the method will run asynchronously: it will return nothing in
>   particular and will not throw an exception.

So whatever value `Template.data.champ` is assigned, it's "nothing in particular" (note that what you return from the callback you have will never be used anywhere).

You could store it in a Session like this:

```js
Session.setDefault('theData', [])

Meteor.call("checkLeague", function(error, results) {
    Session.set('theData', results.data.data)
});

Template.data.champ = function(){
    return Session.get('theData')
}
```

But I would try to go with a collection instead.

Comment: What would be the best solution to this problem then? As I read on wards it seem that the result would be available in `result` and error in `error`.

Comment: @Maaz Dou! Changed my answer, but David already posted that solution ^^'

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what was said about using a session variable. I think you will also need to transform your list into a list of just objects instead of a list of key, value you pairs.

So instead you want to make your data just like this

```
var champ = [{ id: "Aatrox",
   image: Object,
   key: "266",
   name: "Aatrox",
   title: "the Darkin Blade"},   
   { id: "Ahri",
   image: Object,
   key: "267",
   name: "Ahri",
   title: "Hitchhikers Guide"}, ... ];

return champ;
```

To get this structure from your current structure you'll need to do something like

```
var champ = [];

for (var a in results.data.data) {
  for (var key in results.data.data[a]) {
      champ.push(results.data.data[a][key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I get that sort of structure with my current structure? The data is actually coming from an API that's returning a jSON object.

Comment: Just updated my answer. I think you will also need to do what David Weldon said.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might just be that #each is expecting an array and you are passing an object.  In your helper, try `return _.toArray( result.data.data );`.

I couldn't find any mention of this in the meteor docs but [handlebars.js docs mentions Array](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html).  Also, I have passed Array before and it works.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at the return from the method callback and confusing it with the return from the helper.  Peppe's answer below points this out and using [Meteor.call in a template helper is discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15186805/728291).

Comment: After the other answers about the Meteor.call issue, it does indeed seem that handlebars expects an array, so your answer definitely helped. Thanks!