# how to access an object from meteor.call

Tags: templates, object, meteor, callback, server

Just trying to figure things out in Meteor JS. I am stuck trying to get a Meteor.call result object passed back into a template. Here is my code:

### HTML Template

```
<template name="showTotals">
    <div class="container">
        {{#each recordCnt}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

### Client JS

```
//get a count per item
Template.showTotals.recordCnt = function(){

    Meteor.call('getCounts', function(err, result) {
    if (result) {
        //console.log(result); <-this shows object in javascript console
        return result;
        }
        else {
            console.log("blaaaa");
        }
    });

}
```

### Server JS

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

    Meteor.methods({

      getCounts: function() {
        var pipeline = [{$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum : 1}}}];
        count_results = MyCollection.aggregate(pipeline);
        return count_results;
      }
    });
  });
```

### Global JS

```
MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection('folks');
```

I have tried adding a console.log(result) for the results of the call, and it displays in the javascript console with the expected results. I cannot get this to populate recordCnt however.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't do it the way you want because the callback from the `Meteor.call` runs asynchronously.

You can, however, use the callback to set a Session value and have your helper read `Session.get()` instead.

```
Template.showTotals.rcdCount = function() {
  return Session.get('rcdCount');
}

Template.showTotals.rendered = function() {
  Meteor.call('getCounts', function(err, result) {
    if (result) {
        Session.set('rcdCount', result);
        }
        else {
            console.log("blaaaa");
        }
    });
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185923/meteor-call-from-a-handlebars-block-helper) for a similar answer that includes an example of a "hacky" way of doing it.

Comment: `Template.showTotals.rcdCount = function() {}` delcairng helpers like that is to way old

Comment: This worked. Are sessions ok for limited for large data sets? What would happen if I were trying to pull 500 records, etc?

Comment: Look into doing that with a custom publication.  `Meteor.publish` can do more than just publish a cursor.  Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565654/how-does-the-messages-count-example-in-meteor-docs-work) for a very detailed example.  This may be a better way to accomplish what you're trying to do in your question.